# Hdri, controlling the image exposure vs the light it is casting

Tags: hdri

I have a scene where I am using a HDRI as the environment lighting but also using it as the background image, now the problem I have is that the image seems to be a lot darker than the light it is casting into my scene, so it looks slightly odd, is there away to make the background image brighter without effecting the light it is casting into my scene? [image]

As you can see in the image i provided, the trees almost seem black, i want to lighting up the sky and the trees without effecting the light in my scene.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's a very useful article on the subject [here](https://meshlogic.github.io/posts/blender/rendering/nodes-correct-hdri/)